# Is there a way to lower HTTPS requests where I have to request a large amount of IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I have a site, say `example.com`

And I have an array of IDs that can correspond to raw JSON on the site.

I can request it via `example.com/<name>/<id>`

Thing is, the amount of IDs I have is over 100. So, I have to make over 100 HTTPs requests. I don't think the site can let me do `example.com/<name>?ids=[ids]`(plug in the array of IDs as a component). Is there a way I can optimize this?

I'm using Node.JS, the HTTPS module.

Comment: you can use post request instead

Comment: If the API doesn't support batching requests, there is almost nothing you can do. You can try to space out the requests, to not hammer the site all at once and you can them (if applicable) to avoid asking for repeat information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the whole list into chunks (let's say of the length = 5) and make all requests in this chunk in parallel. That way you can optimize a time needed to make all requests and at the same time not to overload that site by making all requests in parallel.

```
// this is `chunk` function from `lodash` package
const idChunks = _.chunk(ids, 5);

for (const idChunk of idChunks) {
  // I'm using axios here only for the demonstration purposes
  const results = await Promise.all(idChunk.map(id => axios.get(`example.com/<name>/${id}`)))
 ...
 // processing results
}
```